# Cannot enter while loop. Is it to do with using an unordered map?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, enums, hashmap

I am trying to do a coding challenge where we have to shorten and minimise direction instructions. I am using an unordered map prior to implementing the while loop. The rest of the code works as expected but the while loop cannot be reached so I cannot output an appropriate value.

```
std::vector<std::string> dirReduc(std::vector <std::string>& arr)
{
    enum Direction
    {
        NORTH = 1, SOUTH = -1,
        EAST = 1, WEST = -1
    };
    int x=0, y=0;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Direction> uMapDir = { {"North",NORTH},{"NORTH",NORTH},
                                                        {"South",SOUTH},{"SOUTH",SOUTH},
                                                        {"East",EAST},{"EAST",EAST},
                                                        {"West",WEST},{"WEST",WEST} };
    for (std::vector<std::string> ::const_iterator i =arr.begin(); i!=arr.end() ; i ++)
    {
        if ((*i=="North")||(*i == "NORTH")||(*i=="South")|| (*i == "SOUTH"))
        {
            y += uMapDir[*i];
        }
        else
        {
            x += uMapDir[*i];
        }
    }
    std::vector<std::string> outPutArr;
    while ((x!=0)&&(y!=0))
    {
        if (x<0)
        {
            x++;
            outPutArr.push_back("WEST");
        }
        else
        {
            x--;
            outPutArr.push_back("EAST");
        }

        if (y < 0)
        {
            y++;
            outPutArr.push_back("SOUTH");
        }
        else
        {
            y--;
            outPutArr.push_back("NORTH");
        }
    }
    return outPutArr;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: convert all the input to a single case so you have to deal with fewer tests.

Comment: Note: For so few elements the `unordered_map` is probably slower than a linear search. Especially when you consider `if ((*i=="North")||(*i == "NORTH")||(*i=="South")|| (*i == "SOUTH"))` has already done most of that work.

Comment: @user4581301 the test cases include both variables

Comment: So you are saying it would be faster to nest if statements

Comment: It could be. An `unordered_map` is smarter, but those smarts have start-up costs that you need to overcome. I'd use the `unordered_map` for something like this to make the code simpler, but it would be a map of a string to a function to be called when the string is found. This means you only have one look-up and the function does all of the other work for that specific direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to do both `x` and `y` in the same loop. This means every loop you must `push_back` an east or west ***AND*** `push_back` a south or north. But that doesn't make any sense. What if you don't have the same number of each?

Instead, you should use two loops:

```
while (x)
{
    if (x<0)
    {
        x++;
        outPutArr.push_back("WEST");
    }
    else
    {
        x--;
        outPutArr.push_back("EAST");
    }
}

while(y) {
    if (y < 0)
    {
        y++;
        outPutArr.push_back("SOUTH");
    }
    else
    {
        y--;
        outPutArr.push_back("NORTH");
    }
}
```